# Convert first row of excel into dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to convert first header row of excel table into dict with a value of 1. Fairly new to Python and not able to excute this code. My table in spreadhseet looks like:

| Matrix | Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Row A | 10 | 20 |
| Row B | 30 | 40 |

I would like my output as following dict:
{'Column A': 1,'Column B': 1}

I tried `test_row = pd.read_excel("Test.xlsx", index_col=0).to_dict('index')`

The column names will increase in future. So, it will be nice to have a solution that can extract n number of columns header into dict with a value of 1. Many thanks!

Comment: What format is the table currently in?  Is it a CSV file? An Excel file? A Pandas DataFrame? A Spark Dataframe? Something else? Please add the code leading up to the `df.to_dict()` and the actual error message.

Comment: Assuming you have read your excel sheet into a DataFrame `df` you can do `dict.fromkeys(df.columns, 1)`

Comment: The table is in format of excel. I tried using `test_row = pd.read_excel("Test.xlsx", index_col=0).to_dict('index')` but I would like value of first elemets of row in dictionary format as 1

Comment: @StevenRumbalski this works! thank you. Also, do you know the code if I would like to apply same problem to first value of each row instead of columns?

Comment: @StevenRumbalski I meant to say that output is `{'Row A': 1,'Row B': 1}` from given table. Thanks!

Comment: Where are the `1`s in your expected output coming from? Do you want a dictionary with the index as keys and all the values set to 1?

Comment: @IgnatiusReilly precisely! I would like both column and rows index keys with values set to 1.

Comment: `{key: 1 for key in df.index}`. Not sure why do you need this, but [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) may be a better tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your example Dataframe as

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Matrix': {0: 'Row A', 1: 'Row B'}, 'Column A': {0: 10, 1: 30}, 'Column B': {0: 20, 1: 40}})
```

You can use:

```
cols_dict = {col: 1 for col in df.columns}  # {'Matrix': 1, 'Column A': 1, 'Column B': 1}
rows_dict = {row: 1 for row in df.Matrix}  # {'Row A': 1, 'Row B': 1}
```